# How to get dropdown selected value without dropdown name, id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

My dropdown,
MVC Code

```
@foreach (var attribute in Model)
{
    string controlId = string.Format("product_attribute_{0}_{1}_{2}", attribute.ProductId, attribute.ProductAttributeId, attribute.Id);
    @switch (attribute.AttributeControlType)
    {
        case AttributeControlType.DropdownList:
        {
            <select name="@(controlId)" id="@(controlId)">

                @foreach (var pvaValue in attribute.Values)
                {
                    <option>@pvaValue.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Html generated code:

```
<dd>
  <select id="product_attribute_5_1_13" name="product_attribute_5_1_13">
    <option value="36">Black</option>
    <option value="37">White</option>
  </select>
</dd>

<dd>
  <select id="product_attribute_5_2_14" name="product_attribute_5_2_14" class="valid">
    <option value="38" selected="selected">1 test</option>
    <option value="39">2 Test</option>
  </select>
</dd>
```

Now i want second dropdown selected item or value using jquery.

**Notes**:
Its id and name value is dynamic for all dropdown.

How do I get dropdown selected value on button click?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking without some context. We can't use ID, class, or name. What's left? There may be a way to get it with `this`, but we have no way of knowing what might be useful. Please remove all references to ASP in your code and tags and show us some of your JavaScript.

Comment: The value of which dropdown. What have you tried?

Comment: this dropdown product_attribute_5_2_14 using jquery or javascript

Comment: `$('#product_attribute_5_2_14).val();`

Comment: but see its dynamic 2 is attribute id when admin delete this value and again insert data then id generate 3. its dynaminc

Comment: I asked you which one and you said `product_attribute_5_2_14`. So again, which one do you want the value of? - the first one, the last one, all of them? Nothing here makes sense. What do you think `selected="@pvaValue.IsPreSelected"` will do - its will always select the last option

Comment: see just html code we have okay? and those dropdowns id and name are dynamic genrate so how to get selected value of this product_attribute_5_2_14 dropdown in jquery

Comment: That's what I'm looking at. What is your trying to do?

Comment: Nothing i am tried because id and name are dynamics so how to get value? and also dont know how many dropdown here becuase its depend on admin side. if one dropdown then i know how to get but here many

Comment: Probably if you take a bigger picture view of your task ... form- or page-level .... you might be able to ask a question that can easily be answered. Why not give it a try? What **in the end** do you plan to achieve?

Comment: okay give me a min i will more specific my question.

Comment: `$('select').eq(1).val();` will return the value of the second `select`

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, your question is not clear. You have made no mention of a form, so I wont assume that the button being clicked is a form submit button. The only logic way to look at this is for you to get back an array/object representing `name/value` pairs of **all** `select`elements on the page upon button click:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var values = $('select').map(function(i,sel) {
            var val = {};
            val[sel.name] = sel.value;
            return val;
        }).get();
    });
    console.log( values );
    //sample output: [{"product_attribute_5_2_13":"36"}, {"product_attribute_5_2_14":"38"}]
});
```